# How add text over signature field using itext

Tags: java, pdf, itext, field, signature

I am working with:
itext-2.1.7 + Java 1.6 + bcmail-jdk14-1.38.jar + bcprov-jdk14-1.38.jar + bctsp-jdk14-1.38.jar
The visualization of the pdf i made with DigiSigner Applet (http://www.digisigner.com/)

I use de follow function **addSignatureField** to create the signature fields.
This function add the signature field with color style. But I need also add some kind of title or label indication with the user name of who should sign in this field.
How can I add this title over the signature field and when the user sign the pdf the title should disapear?

my function to create signature fields:

```
public static void addSignatureField(PdfStamper stamper, int page, Rectangle rectangle, String fieldName)
    {
        //create signature field
        PdfFormField signatureField = PdfFormField.createSignature(stamper.getWriter());
        signatureField.setPage(page);
        signatureField.setWidget(rectangle, null);
        signatureField.setFieldName(fieldName);
        signatureField.setFlags(PdfAnnotation.FLAGS_PRINT);

        // border color
        signatureField.setMKBorderColor(Color.BLACK);
        // background color
        signatureField.setMKBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);

        // add field to document
        stamper.addAnnotation(signatureField, page);
}
```

**output image with my actual signature field in the pdf file** -> [screenshot of my software](https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B_v2tw-6TH3iSXNGQmpFX2MzM0U/edit?usp=sharing)

Over this signature field should be a text title who say "*Sign here, you John Doe!*"

Comment: iText 2.1.7 is 4 years old. Signature technology has evolved in those 4 years. You can't make any future-proof signature with an iText version that old. Start by reading http://itextpdf.com/book/digitalsignatures and you'll know why you should upgrade. You'll also find the answer to your question on p38-40.

Comment: Ok I see. iText in the new version support this feature. Here is the code that I should add for do this. But I will need to upgrade the last version of iText.
`code
// maybe you want to define an appearance
PdfAppearance tp = PdfAppearance.createAppearance(writer, 72, 48);

tp.setColorStroke(BaseColor.BLUE);

tp.setColorFill(BaseColor.LIGHT_GRAY);

tp.rectangle(0.5f, 0.5f, 71.5f, 47.5f);

tp.fillStroke();

tp.setColorFill(BaseColor.BLUE);

ColumnText.showTextAligned(tp, Element.ALIGN_CENTER,
new Phrase("SIGN HERE"), 36, 24, 25);

field.setAppearance(PdfAnnotation.APPEARANCE_NORMAL, tp);
`

Comment: Thanks Bruno for you answer,